# Customizing Label and points in android plot

Tags: android, androidplot

I am developing app using android plot , I am trying to beautify it I want it like in the image

[image: one]

But I am getting like below

[image: two]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer addresses drawing the inner circles for the individual points as in your example image above)

Normally this would be a 2 or 3 line job where simply re-adding the series with a properly configured instance of LineAndPointFormatter would do the trick but there's a bug in recent releases that prevents the same series from being added more than once using the same Renderer, regardless of whether or not a different Formatter is supplied. (Will be fixed in the 1.2.3 release)

If you dont mind having a complete duplicate of your series data you can still do this fairly easily:

```
        XYSeries series2b = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(series2Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");

        LineAndPointFormatter series2bFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter(null, Color.WHITE, null, null);

        // this adjusts the size of the inner circle:
        series2bFormat.getVertexPaint().setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(7));

        ...

        // make sure this line comes AFTER the addSeries call for the copied series:
        plot.addSeries(series2b, series2bFormat);
```

A limitation of the above implementation is that it will draw a duplicate legend icon (also addressed in the upcoming 1.2.3 release). An alternative approach that avoids the duplicate icon is to make a custom extends of LineAndPointRenderer along with a custom LineAndPointFormatter:

```
    // a custom renderer to draw an second smaller circle for each rendered vertex
    static class MyLineAndPointRenderer extends LineAndPointRenderer<MyLineAndPointFormatter> {


        public MyLineAndPointRenderer(XYPlot plot) {
            super(plot);
        }

        @Override
        protected void renderPoints(Canvas canvas, RectF plotArea, XYSeries series, List<PointF> points,
                LineAndPointFormatter formatter) {
            // draw points as normal:
            super.renderPoints(canvas, plotArea, series, points, formatter);

            // now draw our inner vertices on top of the previously drawn vertices:
            for (PointF p : points) {
                Paint paint = ((MyLineAndPointFormatter) formatter).getInnerPointPaint();
                canvas.drawPoint(p.x, p.y, paint);
            }
        }
    }

    // defines the format for our custom renderer:
    static class MyLineAndPointFormatter extends LineAndPointFormatter {

        Paint innerPointPaint = new Paint();

        {
            // setup innPointPaint to draw a white circle a little smaller than the 
            // typical circle drawn for each vertex:
            innerPointPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            innerPointPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            innerPointPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            innerPointPaint.setStrokeWidth(PixelUtils.dpToPix(7));
        }

        public MyLineAndPointFormatter(Context context, int xmlCfgId) {
            super(context, xmlCfgId);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends SeriesRenderer> getRendererClass() {
            return MyLineAndPointRenderer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public SeriesRenderer getRendererInstance(XYPlot plot) {
            return new MyLineAndPointRenderer(plot);
        }

        public Paint getInnerPointPaint() {
            return innerPointPaint;
        }
    }
```

Then, use the above instead of LineAndPointFormatter when adding your series to the plot:

```
MyLineAndPointFormatter series1Format =
                new MyLineAndPointFormatter(this, R.xml.my_format);
```

While this last approach is more code, its also the most efficient and extensible.

Comment: Thank you Nick ,I will try this .

Comment: Nick,I tried 2nd solution but getting error at constructor of MyLineAndPointFormatter super(context,xmlcfg);"Cannot resolve symbol" also at @override public SeriesRenderer doGetRendererInstance(XYPlot plot) {
            return new MyLineAndPointRenderer(plot);
        } "Method doesnot override method from super class"

Comment: Apologies - I was on a dev branch when I wrote that.  The correct name for the method is `SeriesRenderer getRendererInstance(XYPlot plot)`.  I've updated the code above to reflect this.